# Read/Write lock for linux kernel module

Tags: linux, multithreading, locking

I'm trying to protect my `list` with data using read/write locks, i found solution in this thread:
[What's the best linux kernel locking mechanism for a specific scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932197/whats-the-best-linux-kernel-locking-mechanism-for-a-specific-scenario)

But i can't find needed headers for this solution, seems it is outdated, error:

`error: ‘RW_LOCK_UNLOCKED’ undeclared here (not in a function)`

Using `<linux/spinlock.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RW_LOCK_UNLOCKED` has been deprecated for a long time and finally removed in Linux 2.6.39, so now, [according to the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/locking/spinlocks.txt):

> For dynamic initialization, use spin_lock_init() or rwlock_init() as
>   appropriate:
>
> ...
>
> For static initialization, use DEFINE_SPINLOCK() / DEFINE_RWLOCK() or
>   __SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED() / __RW_LOCK_UNLOCKED() as appropriate.

Like

```
static DEFINE_RWLOCK(myrwlock);
```

or

```
rwlock_t myrwlock;
static int __init rwlock_init(void)
{
    rwlock_init(&myrwlock);
}
```

instead of

```
rwlock_t myrwlock = RW_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
```